# setting the level of pyramid for VGG's VL_PHOW

Tags: vlfeat

Long time ago I applied a old version of a PHOW library (https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/caltech/) with very good results for training a neural net. 
Nowadays I would like to test the new version embedded in VL_phow, but I couldn't find how to set a value for the level of the spatial pyramid (that constitutes the PHOW descriptor). I have been looking for this peace of information in every place in the web. Could someone please indicate me where can I get this?
Thanks